# Core Data: How to fetch Entities based on an attribute of a related entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

This is what the pertinent part of my object graph looks like:

```
[Anime] <->> [AnimeName @string @type]
```

So an `Anime` object has many `AnimeName` objects that contain a string and the type of name they are. Now to implement a "Search by Name" feature, I would need a predicate that matches all `Anime` entities where any name contains the search string. What I have tried so far is this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Anime"];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"names.string == %@", searchString]];
```

on an `NSFetchRequest` of `Anime` entities, this however gives the following error:

```
"NSInvalidArgumentException", "to-many key not allowed here"
```

Which makes perfect sense to me, and I could simply work around that by using this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AnimeName"];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"string == %@", searchString]];
```

and then getting the relationship to the `Anime` entity from each returned object, but then how do I plug that into an `NSFetchedResultsController` for my `UITableView`?

Please help if anyone knows a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For to-many relationships, use "ANY":

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Anime"];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY names.string == %@", searchString]];
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, for some reason it never occurred to me to use ANY like that.